# Highlighting the changed line in the source file in the resulting pdf using auctex and pdf-tools?

Tags: init-file, latex, auctex, pdf, highlighting

Is it possible to highlight the changed line in the resulting pdf using auctex and pdf-tools. I have this feature enabled in Skim with the following lines in my setup.

```
    (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
                             (push
                              '("pdflatex" "pdflatex -synctex=1 %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
                                :help "Run pdflatex with SyncTex on file")
                              TeX-command-list)))
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (setq TeX-command-default "pdflatex")))
(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("PDF Viewer" "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -b -g %n %o %b"))))
```

Comment: If there will be no answer here, I'd suggest you to open a ticket on https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues  to request this feature.  A comment about your code: why don't you just enable `TeX-source-correlate-mode` (`(setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)` in your init file, and `TeX-PDF-mode` has been on by default for more than one year now) instead of defining a new useless entry for `TeX-command-list`?

Comment: This is an old piece of code that I copied and pasted long time ago. I'll update my setup and also open a ticket if I get no replies. Thanks!